# Image fails to upload (Image Intervertion Laravel)

Tags: php, html, laravel, intervention

I am resizing an image with image intervention package. I have successfully uploaded a number of files after resize. But now it's not working.
Every time i tried to upload image it shows error "Image failed to upload".
I have also increase the file size in configuration file but didn't solve the problem.

**My Controller:**

```
 $file = \Request::file('feature_image');

        if (!$file == "") {

            // validate the posted data
            $validator = $request->validate([
                'feature_image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:2048'
            ]);

                $path = storage_path().'/images/blog/'.$blog->featured_image;
                // delete the previous featured image
                @unlink($path);
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $orginalFileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $filename = pathinfo($orginalFileName , PATHINFO_FILENAME).'_'.rand();
                $org_name = $filename.'.'.$extension;

                // $thumbnail = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
                // now you are able to resize the instance
                // $thumbnail->resize(350, 233)->save(storage_path().'/images/blog/thumbnail/'. $org_name);

                $featuredImage = Image::make($request->file('feature_image')->getRealPath());
                // now you are able to resize the instance
                $featuredImage->resize(730, 487)->save(storage_path().'/images/blog/'. $org_name);

                // $file->move(storage_path().'/images/blog',$org_name);
               $blog->featured_image = $org_name;
               $blog->save();
        }
```

**My Html:**

```
<form class="form-floating" action="{{url('edit_blog/'.request()->id)}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
<label for="exampleInputFile"><b>Feature Image<span class="post-required">*</span></b></label>
 <input type="file" name="feature_image" id="feature_image">
</form>
```

I don't know what's the actual problem. I have already spent alot of time over it and i will appreciate if anyone could help me in this regard.
Thanks,

> Note: The package working correctly on my localhost.

Comment: Have you checked the server's `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`?

Comment: Yes, everything fine there. I am confused why it worked fine in the beginning and now  it's throwing exception.

Comment: Which part of the code throws the error?

Comment: if i include the laravel validation code it doesn't throw any exception nor report error in the log section but if i remove the validation section it throw exception like:
"local.ERROR: Image source not readable {"exception":"[object] (Intervention\\Image\\Exception\\NotReadableException(code: 0): Image source not readable at /home/vtvtdialer/public_html/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/AbstractDecoder.php:346)
[stacktrace]"

Comment: I have updated my composer, clear cache/config as well. Nothing happend...

Comment: Try commenting out code to narrow down on the error producing code

Comment: I have even remove the intervention code and tried to upload the image manually but still same issue. Thanks for so much support. I will let you know if i found anything.